# How to change datepicker format?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins, datepicker

I'm using Option Tree plugin for add more metaboxes to my site, i'm using date-picker, but the format is in yy-mm-dd

Option Tree have filter to change this:

```
/* filter date format */
$date_format = apply_filters( 'ot_type_date_picker_date_format', 'yy-mm-dd', $field_id );
```

But i not understand how to apply new filter to override this in my functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'ot_type_date_picker_date_format', 'dd-mm-yy', $field_id );
```

This not work for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WordPress filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) work with function callbacks.

`apply_filters` calls the hooks defined for the tag `'ot_type_date_picker_date_format'` (first argument) with as arguments `'yy-mm-dd'` and `$field_id`. Thus, the `add_filter` should probably look something like this:

```
add_filter('ot_type_date_picker_date_format', function($format, $field_id) {
   return 'dd-mm-yy';
});
```

-- edit -- after a quick Google search, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/cec1418a2ed50c641adc) might be of more help

Comment: Okay, this work fine. TIP: Update the post after change functions.php